# Android package names

Tags: java, android, package

In an Android application, I notice that the package name of a class does not have to match the name that was generated when I created the new project. In other areas, Java is insistent that everything matches. I would like to understand why this is not the case for package names, and what the implications are.

Example: I create a new project named TextToSpeech, using my own reverse domain name. This gives a package name of `com.lexogram.texttospeech`; the path to the MainActivity.java class file is `TextToSpeech/app/src/man/java/com.lexogram.texttospeech/`.

I now go to a [TextToSpeech tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm) and copy-and-paste the code into my project. This code uses `com.example.texttospeech` as the package name, both in the MainActivity class and in the AndroidManifest.xml. I run the project, and everything works fine.

Does this mean that each activity can use a different package name, so long as the name is used consistently across all files in the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is that your project can have multiple packages inside of it.

[Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) explains them nicely:

> To make types easier to find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and
>   to control access, programmers bundle groups of related types into
>   packages.

Comment: Suppose I have a set of files that deal (say) with Text To Speech, and another set of files that deal with Pattern Recognition. These sets will include classes, layouts and resources. If I understand correctly, I should create a separate package for each of them, and save the classes in separate sub-directories of the java/ folder. For example: java/com/example/texttospeech/TTS.java, java/com/example/patternrecognition/PatternRecognition.java, and so on. Is that what your answer implies?

Comment: @JamesNewton big projects are split to packages, so it's easier to manage hundreds of files and browse to find something you need. Personally I split my application functionality into sub packages, just like you mentioned in your example of text recognition.